# Why chart dont load when i change json file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, highcharts

I started using highcharts today and tried to use the code provided by them but when I change the url of the json file, the graphic does not load anymore

inicial code:

```
 $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data)
```

i change for:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:55529/content/dados/data.json', function (data)
```

my json file:

```
[
[Date.UTC(2013,5,2),0.7695],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,3),0.7648]
]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: could you please make fiddle or something?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1v9hp67r/

Comment: might be, it is happening because of before come response from ajax graph is loaded already.

Comment: Have you investigated whether the json data is actually being returned by the call when you point the url to local? I would use alert() in the function receiving the data, just to see whether there is actually anything coming back. An example of the kind of issue that could be preventing your call from returning data is that your url is hard coded with a port; is the port always staying the same? In any case, until you know whether data is coming back, it is impossible to debug further.

Comment: I've created the fiddle and I do not have any problem with the code you provided. http://jsfiddle.net/1v9hp67r/4/ Or maybe you use arrays inside arrays as strings and you neet to parse it to a javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$.getJSON()` is `async`, your graph is probably loading before you got the response.

You have two options to solve this;

Change your JSON to;

```
callback([
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,2),0.7695],
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,3),0.7648]
]);
```

AND your `$.getJSON()` to;

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:55529/content/dados/data.json&callback=?', function (data)
```

OR;

Keep everything as it is but don't use `$.getJSON()`, instead;

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:55529/content/dados/data.json',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    mydata = data.whatever;
  }
});
```